# Why would one use the |= operator on a boolean value in C#?

Tags: c#, boolean

Example:

We found this is some vendor written code and we're trying to figure out why they'd do this.

```
bool tmp = false;

if (somecase)
   tmp = true;

if (someOtherCase)
   tmp |= true;
```

Comment: Is the right side really a constant `true`? Using `|=` on bools is perfectly reasonable, using `|= true` rarely is.

Comment: You are aware that even [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h5f1zzaw.aspx) lists a boolean and the `|=` operators in its example...

Answer (score 69, accepted):

For no good reason at all. A boolean value `|= true` will always be `true`. This is someone trying to be fancy, or forgetting boolean logic =)

Change it to `tmp = true;`.

Comment: Thank you after a few test programs I came to that conclusion.. which is why I asked.. can't be to safe.

Comment: @code4life: `false | true` is still `true`... Are you forgetting your boolean logic, too?

Comment: @code4life: OK, what if it was? Then what is its state after "tmp |= true;"?

Comment: tmp |= someOtherCase;   would make more sense. Perhaps it started that way and was carelessly converted to the more complex form with an if.

Comment: `|= false` is also useless: It's a no-op.

Answer (score 17):

Perhaps one of the boolean literals used to be a variable, and they just didn't think to change the operator when they changed the operand.  Obviously the logic is equivalent.

More likely, they were thinking that in the second case, they want to retain the result of evaluating the first "if" condition.  Of course, that's false reasoning.

A simpler equivalent statement:

```
bool tmp = somecase | someOtherCase;
```

EDIT

As pickypg notes, this statement could be confusing, since most people don't expect `|` with boolean values, and many won't notice it, or won't think about the implications for side effects.  The best way to be explicit (if indeed there are side effects) would be minitech's solution: just change the `|=` to `=`.

Or, if there are no side effects to the `someOtherCase` expression, use Jakub Konecki's solution : `someCase || someOtherCase`.

Comment: That's what we thought.. or maybe a lucky type-o.

Comment: I suspect that was the original code, but even that should be converted to `bool tmp = somecase || someOtherCase;` to let short circuiting do its job. If you want the side effects, then chances are you're destroying readability by one-lining the code, particularly by implicitly associating the two methods that can only be loosely associated at that point (as the first is not preventing the second by "failing" or whatever `false` represents).

Comment: @pickypg I agree that one-lining the code with `|` decreases readability.  There's also a huge chance that someone will "correct" the `|` to `||` at some point.  Both of these are true because using `|` with boolean values isn't really idiomatic C#.  I find that a shame, but there's not much to be done about it.

Answer (score 7):

Interesting - that looks like it's doing the equivalent:

```
tmp = tmp | true;
```

Which will always set tmp to true.

Answer (score 6):

`foo |= true` is a short version of `foo = foo | true`.

The actual code can be rewritten as

```
bool tmp = false;
tmp |= someCase;
tmp |= someOtherCase;
```

Or even better as

```
someCase || someOtherCase
```

Comment: Small quibble: If someOtherCase has side effects, `someCase | someOtherCase` would preserve them, while `someCase || someOtherCase` would not.

Answer (score 4):

Like the other op= operators, `x |= y` is equivalent (except for multiple-evaluation side effects) to `x = x | y`.  This is a terse way of writing `if (!x) x = y;` or  `if (y) x = true;`.

However, it doesn't make any sense to have a *constant* on the right-hand side.

- `x |= true` is more straightforwardly written as `x = true`
- `x |= false` leaves `x` unchanged.

> why they'd do this.

Some possible explanations are:

- It's a typo: They meant to write `tmp = true;` instead of `tmp |= true;`, but never noticed it because their program happened to work as expected.
- The RHS was originally a variable, which was replaced with the constant `true` without otherwise changing the code.
- `tmp` was originally a [bitfield](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit_field) (for which `|=` makes more sense), which was later reduced to a single bit.

Answer (score 2):

The ultimate result will be "If any of the cases is true, the result will be true." There is no reason that you have to use the operator though, since the `||` in an `if` would work just as well.

Comment: If `someOtherCase` has side effects, you'd need to use `|` rather than `||` to preserve them.

Answer (score 1):

A clever compiler could avoid the assignment in this case, though it probably wouldn't as it shouldn't short-circuit a bitwise operation. In any event, it seems like a micro-optimization.  In reality I suspect it's a hold-over pattern the author has from using bit flags (or s/he just doesn't understand how it works).  It would be better as:

```
bool tmp = somecase || someOthercase;
```

(and then inline the temporary if you only use it once)

Note that, when using flags, it does make sense.

```
#define CONDITION_ONE 0x01
#define CONDITION_TWO 0x02

int temp = 0;
if (somecase) {
   temp = CONDITION_ONE;
}

if (someOthercase) {
   temp |= CONDITION_TWO;
}
```

Comment: This does not preserve side effects of `someOtherCase`, if there are any to be preserved.

Comment: @phoog - that's true.  if the cases are functions or otherwise contain statements, then using lazy evaluation wouldn't be the same and they shouldn't be combined.

Comment: You could combine them with the `|` operator.

Comment: @phoog that would be the purest sort of evil.  IMO, depending on the reader to distinguish between bitwise OR and logical OR to determine the evaluation of a statement (on booleans) is the worst sort of coding magic.  I'd rather split the condition and evaluate in two statements to make it clear what the expectations are.  I've long used the rule that you only use logical operators on boolean variables.

Comment: I agree with you; the subtle difference between the two operators makes it far too easy to misread one for the other.  Your terminology doesn't agree with Microsoft's, however; they classify both operators as logical, and make a distinction between bitwise logic and boolean logic: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6a71f45d(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: @phoog - it's funny, I completely missed that it was C# and was assuming C++.  I'm going to have to pretend that the non-shortciruiting operator doesn't even exist for booleans in C#.  It's not worth mucking up readability.

Comment: I made the reverse mistake once -- my highest-voted answer ever was for a C++ question that I thought was a C# question.

Answer (score 0):

This is equivalent to

```
tmp = tmp | true;
```

EDIT:
Which is equal to

```
tmp = true;
```

I concur with the rest of the posters here...!

More information [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h5f1zzaw.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

for bools not so much

however for bitflags this can allow code like this:

```
int flags=0;
flags|=READ;
//flags|=UPDATE;
foo(arg,flags);
```

this allows some flags to be easily commented out (and makes the used flags a tad more readable IMO)

Answer (score -1):

Its an expression using the |= assignment operator. Check [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h5f1zzaw.aspx)

Comment: Yeah I looked and understood it just didn't make sense where they used it in the code I had.